# Sort the program list on EV3

Tags: ev3, programming, fll

When uploading a project to the EV3 brick, is there a way to control the sorting order of the programs on the brick?

E.g:
Prog_1
Prog_2
Prog_3
...

When playing a robot match in FLL one often needs to start a number of programs in a pre defined order, but we are unable to sort the program list. Resulting in much time waisted looking for the correct program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without hacking the firmware, which would be against FLL rules.

One solution I have seen many teams use it to only write one program. This program has it's own menu (that you have to make yourself as part of the program) that calls subprograms (presumably saved as My Blocks).

Comment: Thx!
Good idea with the menu and subprograms, will try that.

Answer (score 2):

There's not an easy way to do it, but a workaround I've found is to go to the project management tab (which is the wrench icon next to the programs at the top of a project) and export each program using the export button at the bottom. Then, delete all the programs from the project and reimport them in reverse order from you want them to appear on the robot. Make sure the program you want to appear first in the list is open when you click download, and the programs should be in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way besides running the programs in the opposite order of which you need it to be. If it doesn't work try again.

Comment: Yes, I guess this would work.
For FLL this year, we made a startup menu with all the missions saved as "my blocks".
This worked very well for us.